# How to handle the pandas gbq related exception?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am querying Google BigQuery using pandas-gbq. I'm wondering if there is any possible ways to handle the exception raised by pandas-gbq.

I tried `GenericGBQException` in `except` but that gave me the following error:

> NameError: global name 'GenericGBQException' is not defined.

I tried to put only `except` in exception but that too is not working.

```
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(json.key)

def query_to_dataframe(query):
    try:
        return pd.read_gbq(query,
                     project_id=project_id,
                     credentials=credentials,
                     dialect='standard')
    except GenericGBQException:
        print("failed")
query = """
SELECT 

*FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170801` """

df = query_to_dataframe(query)
print(df)
```

I want something which can tell me what the root cause of failure is.

Comment: You can try by importing this exception class like `from pandas_gbq.gbq import GenericGBQException`

Comment: @Nihal I have tried with above,but I didn't getting anything if my queries is failing. simply no output

Comment: @Zhang I tried that approach as well but that is now working in my case.